# Replace dates in pandas for example Nov/19 to 201911

Tags: python, pandas

How can I replace Nov/19 to 201911, Dec/20 to 202012, etc?

I tried DateTime function but couldn't get it to work

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.
"Couldn't get it to work" is not a problem specification.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Pandas, you can use [`pd.to_datetime()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) together with [`Series.dt.strftime()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) to do the conversion:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%b/%y').dt.strftime('%Y%m')
```

### Demo

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['Nov/19', 'Dec/20']})

print(df)

     date
0  Nov/19
1  Dec/20


df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%b/%y').dt.strftime('%Y%m')

print(df)

     date
0  201911
1  202012
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
from datetime import datetime
txt ="Nov/19"
d = datetime.strptime(txt, '%b/%y')
print(d.strftime('%Y-%m'))
```

Comment: @d8888d  This answer is not for Pandas as you required.